# How to let AUCTeX open PDF with pdf-tools

Tags: auctex, pdf-tools

Some TeX/LaTeX editor has support for embedding PDF viewer, and forward/backward search support.

I want to configure AUCTeX and pdf-tools to this result.

I found a discussion in mailing list.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2015-02/msg00013.html

It give out a method to implement this opening PDF file with pdf-tools in Emacs.
I followed that, but it does not work.

Here is my config:

```lisp
(require 'tex-site)
(require 'latex)

;;; AUCTeX config
(setq TeX-auto-save t
      TeX-parse-self t)

(setq-default TeX-master nil)

;; automatic detection of master file
(defun guess-TeX-master (filename)
  "Guess the master file for FILENAME from currently open .tex files."
  (let ((candidate nil)
        (filename (file-name-nondirectory filename)))
    (save-excursion
      (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
        (with-current-buffer buffer
          (let ((name (buffer-name))
                (file buffer-file-name))
            (if (and file (string-match "\\.tex$" file))
                (progn
                  (goto-char (point-min))
                  (if (re-search-forward (concat "\\\\input{" filename "}") nil t)
                      (setq candidate file))
                  (if (re-search-forward (concat "\\\\include{" (file-name-sans-extension filename) "}") nil t)
                      (setq candidate file))))))))
    (if candidate
        (message "TeX master document: %s" (file-name-nondirectory candidate)))
    candidate))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (setq TeX-master (guess-TeX-master (buffer-file-name)))
             ))

;; enable RefTeX in AUCTeX (LaTeX-mode)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) ; with Emacs latex mode
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex) ; with AUCTeX LaTeX mode

;; view generated PDF with `pdf-tools'.
(unless (assoc "PDF Tools" TeX-view-program-list-builtin)
  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list-builtin
               '("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view)))
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
             '(output-pdf "PDF Tools"))

;; LaTeX source code block syntax highlighting.
;; [ minted ]
;; toggle shell escape using [C-c C-t x].
(defun TeX-toggle-escape ()
  "Toggle Shell Escape"
  (interactive)
  (setq-local LaTeX-command
              (if (string= LaTeX-command "latex") "latex -shell-escape"
                "latex"))
  (message (concat "shell escape "
                   (if (string= LaTeX-command "latex -shell-escape")
                       "enabled"
                     "disabled"))
           ))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-t x") 'TeX-toggle-escape)))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's my setup, using `auctex-11.89` and `pdf-tools-20151224.1159`:

```lisp
;; Use pdf-tools to open PDF files
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))
      TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)

;; Update PDF buffers after successful LaTeX runs
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions
           #'TeX-revert-document-buffer)
```

Comment: Only a comment: `TeX-PDF-mode` is active by default since AUCTeX 11.88.

Comment: I tried your method, it can work when I try with `emacs -q` and load packages. but has problem with my configs. Is there a way to find out why?

Comment: Only thing I can think of: bisect your config file, commenting out piece by piece, trying to nailing it down to the code that is in conflict with my solution.

Comment: FYI: I couldn't find `TeX-after-TeX-LaTeX-command-finished-hook`.  `TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions` now appears to be the relevant hook (or so the docstring says).

Comment: @Dan At least for version 12.1 (2017-12-04), I only see `TeX-after-compilation-finished-hook` in the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.pdf). I think it is no longer either `TeX-after-TeX-LaTeX-command-finished-hook` or `TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions`.

Comment: ... Though it seems that `TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions` still exists, despite no longer being in the manual.