# automatic latex-preview-pane with auctex and or-mode latex export

Tags: org-mode, auctex, hooks, preview-latex

To enable automatic `latex-preview-pane-mode` with `AUCTex` I bound it to a hook:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'latex-preview-pane-mode)
```

This works.
When I open a *.tex file, then `latex-preview-pane-mode` gets enabled.

**BUT:** now when I export a `org-mode` file via latex to pdf (`C-c C-e l o`) two times (or more often), then the latex-preview-pane window (aka `DocView` or `pdf-tools`) is also opened a second time. My frame then shows on both windows the generated pdf. The bad thing is, it breaks `auto-revert` of the pdf-preview (the pdf-view does not get updated to changes anymore).

(removing the above hook, repairs `org-mode`'s latex export. But then `latex-preview-pane-mode` gets not **automatic** enabled from within `AUCTex`)

**Question:**
How can I have `latex-preview-pane-mode` enabled **automatically** and working with both `AUCTex` **and** `org-mode`'s latex export?

*Note:* I have seen 2 similar named questions here, but those have a complete different topic.
*Note:* I added `(add-to-list 'revert-without-query ".+\\.pdf$")` for auto-revert of pdf files to my `init.el`.

Comment: Could it be that you mean `LaTeX-mode-hook` instead of `LaTeX-mode`? Note that `latex-preview-pane-enable` sets `latex-mode-hook` instead. Furthermore could it be that you mean `auto-revert-mode` instead of `auto-reverse`?

Comment: @Tobias I meant auto-revert. ;-) As of the add-hook line, thats correct (I'm using `:hook` from use-package, which just looks slightly different)

Comment: Using the `latex-mode-hook` (instead of LaTeX-mode-hook) by calling `latex-preview-pane-enable`, or ensuring it is `nil`, does not change anything on the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the answer I was looking for, but I want to document this as a usable mode of operation.

I completely kicked the package `latex-preview-pane-mode`.
(For me it now looks like it just adds more complexity.)

Then I found that `org-mode`s latex export works pretty well with pdf-tools and without `latex-preview-pane-mode`.
(Maybe that is the reason org-modes's export did not work well with `latex-preview-pane-mode`, and maybe the `add-hook` mentioned below will fix the revert issue.)

As for `LaTex-mode`: I can live with preview after compile (`TeX-command-run-all` or `C-c C-a`).
To have this properly working I added 3 lines to my init.el:

```
(add-hook 'TeX-after-compilation-finished-functions #'TeX-revert-document-buffer) ;; revert pdf after compile
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Tools"))) ;; use pdf-tools for viewing
(setq LaTeX-command "latex --synctex=1") ;; optional: enable synctex
```

I got it from [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19475).

*More Info on `synctex`* (not related to Question, but mentioned for completeness):
ensure that variable `TeX-source-correlate-method` mentions something like this `(pdf . synctex)`.
and variable `TeX-PDF-mode` is `t`, so `pdflatex` gets called to compile.